# How to read Message from ActiveMQ Without JMS in Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, jms, activemq-classic

Machine 1 - has JMS and ActiveMQ is runnning.

Machine 2 - No JMS and  ActiveMQ is not avialable/runnning.

Please let me know , how machine 2 reads the messages posted by machine 1 .

Comment: If you want to let machine 2 read messages from your ActiveMQ, you would want machine 2 to connect to ActiveMQ with a specific protocol to read messages.
If you're building an application in Java the easiest way to do this is to use JMS (Java Message Service) as this is the protocol for Java to communicate to a message broker.

Comment: Machine 2 - does not have ActiveMQ and cannot be installed is the requirement.

Comment: ActiveMQ is a message broker that is something external to your system. It's not a system you need on every machine separately. Think of it like a temporary database storing data until it is read. You wouldn't need a database on every system that wants to read data. What you want is machine 1 and machine 2 connecting to the same ActiveMQ, otherwise they won't be able to read each others messages. So for machine 2 to read messages from machine 1 you just want machine 2 connecting to the ActiveMQ of machine 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of important starting points:

- All message brokers that I know of (including ActiveMQ) follow a client/server model where a *server* process runs on a particular machine and a *client* process accesses that server over the network. This is the same model followed by, for example, web servers and HTML browsers.
- JMS is an API. It doesn't *run*. It can be used on a client or a server or both.

In your scenario you just need to put the ActiveMQ client libraries and your client application (which will use those libraries via the JMS API) on Machine 2. The client simply needs the hostname and port information for Machine 1 where the server is running in order to connect to it. This assumes, of course, that the server on Machine 1 is configured to be available over the network.

A simple "Hello World" example is available on the [ActiveMQ website](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html).